# <element> vs <composite-element> in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

What is the difference between `<element>` and `<composite-element>`? I have seen both `<composite-element>` and `<element>` tags used within  tag. Are these elements used for collections? In what situations do each of these elements apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<element>` is used when you want to map a collection of "simple" values. See this example from [6.2.4. Collections of values and many-to-many associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues)

```
<set name="names" table="person_names">
    <key column="person_id"/>
    <element column="person_name" type="string"/>
</set>
```

`<composite-element>` is for when you want to map a collection of [components](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-dependentobjects), i.e. dumb classes that are themselves made up of simple types. This example from [8.2. Collections of dependent objects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-incollections):

```
<set name="someNames" table="some_names" lazy="true">
    <key column="id"/>
    <composite-element class="eg.Name"> <!-- class attribute required -->
        <property name="initial"/>
        <property name="first"/>
        <property name="last"/>
    </composite-element>
</set>
```